# can't see app in emulator (netbeans with android)

Tags: android, netbeans, view, screen, emulation

I installed netbeans 7.2.1. and
installed the android plug-in as directed in 
[a link](http://youtu.be/xB2lm8vR6rw)
 But at the end my emulator only shows "android" but not the final
 screen in the vídeo.
 Why is it happening like this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a cup of coffee and wait... Depending on your computer it can take a few minutes for the Emulator to come up. If you see "android" that is a good sign because this is the boot-screen. This is why you should never stop the Emulator. I personally prefer testing on a device.

Comment: Hi! I already works! Now I just want to know how to install an android app in the emulator...

Comment: thanks to accept the answer if it was correct. For the new question I have no idea as I do not use Netbeans. In Eclipse you just hit run and it installs. I guess it should be similar in Netbeans

Comment: yes, it is the same. I would like to give you some points here... how do I do this?

Comment: If you move with your mouse below the 0 in front of the answer, you will see a check-sign that you can click to accept the answer as correct.